# What does "The "DataDirectory" registry value is missing in the LocalDB instance registry key" error mean?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, localdb

I have a MVC4/ASP.Net application that uses localdb. Everything "appears" to work correctly. However I am getting loads of errors in my event log:

> The "DataDirectory" registry value is missing in the LocalDB instance registry key: {BB3F4304-E7E9-4EE7-9A25-B46BFAA73FB4}
>
> The "DataDirectory" registry value is missing in the LocalDB instance registry key: {BB31321B-BEB9-465B-8C8E-DEF9C2C67FBE}

Each time the instance changes.

XML Detail of the error:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="SQLLocalDB 11.0" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="35269">512</EventID> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-03-12T14:12:43.000000000Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>1080755</EventRecordID> 
    <Channel>Application</Channel> 
    <Computer>XXXXXX</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>{BB07CF13-2ABD-4FD5-AB2B-467FF08F28E6}</Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Connection string:

```
<add 
    name="DefaultConnection" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=WebMVCContext-20121205135209; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|WebMVCContext-20121205135209.mdf" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Again, it is working and everything is connecting just get 10-20 of these for every connection.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue. It seems like a bug of Localdb.
I have solved this issue by deleting the registry key:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances\[GUID_FROM_EVENT_LOG]
```

Comment: In Windows Server 2008r2 the path appears to be: HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances. I will give it a try but I have many. many entries. I hope that don't keep generating.

Comment: with sql 2014 same. HKU branch.

Comment: I found it here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances\

Comment: For SQL 2016, I actually found the key at HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances.  For something like this, it's best to use the Registry Editor's find function to look for the GUID.